# Syntax to define a NHibernate Filter with Fluent Nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

It seems I can't find the correct syntax to define a nhibernate filter using fluent Nhibernate.

I'm trying to follow this ayende's blogpost:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/26/LocalizingNHibernateContextualParameters.aspx

I defined the formula on my property with .FormulaIs() method but can't find on google how to translate this definition to fluent nhibernate:

```
 < filter-def name='CultureFilter'>
   < filter-param name='CultureId' type='System.Int32'/>
 < /filter-def>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This recent post](http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/6bb12d91a8d6d09b/755ca6376dc5042c?lnk=gst&q=filter#755ca6376dc5042c) in the Fluent NHibernate discussion leads me to believe that filters are not yet supported by the Fluent API.

Comment: Downvoted because a feature that was not supported at the time of the answer later became supported? That's harsh.

Comment: I agree that a downvote is harsh, but you still may want to update your answer to note the current state of the framework.

Answer (score 61):

If you build Fluent from source, there is now support for filters. You use them like this:

First create a class inheriting from `FluentNHibernate.Mapping.FilterDefinition`:

```
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

namespace PonyApp.FluentFilters
{
    public class PonyConditionFilter : FilterDefinition
    {
        public PonyConditionFilter()
        {
            WithName("PonyConditionFilter")
                .AddParameter("condition",NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.String);
        }
    }
}
```

In your ClassMap for your class, use the ApplyFilter method:

```
namespace PonyApp.Entities.Mappings
{
    public class PonyMap : ClassMap<Pony>
    {
        public PonyMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.PonyName);
            Map(x => x.PonyColor);
            Map(x => x.PonyCondition);
            ApplyFilter<PonyConditionFilter>("PonyCondition = :condition");
        }
    }
}
```

Then add the filter to your fluent config:

```
Fluently.Configure()
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.Add(typeof(PonyConditionFilter)))
    //blah blah bunches of other important stuff left out
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Then you can turn it on and off just as you would with vanilla NHibernate:

```
session.EnableFilter("PonyConditionFilter").SetParameter("condition","Wonderful");
```

Comment: 2013 - this is available now in fluentNHibernate without building from sources.

Comment: Your comment helped me a lot. Thank you.
By the way, the stept to add the filter to your fluent config is not necessary if there is already a line like:
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<PonyMap>())
because Fluent NHibernate will "detect" it.

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone's still watching this, I've just submitted a patch on Google code for Fluent NHibernate to support filters. You can see it in use in snicker's answer above.