# property filter with fluent nHibernate automapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

i'm trying to create a filter, using fluent nH (1.2) automapping with nH 2.1.2.
I've followed the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960625/syntax-to-define-a-nhibernate-filter-with-fluent-nhibernate), but I keep getting the exception:

```
filter-def for filter named 'DateFilter' was never used to filter classes nor collections..
```

the filter class:

```
public class DateFilter : FilterDefinition
    {
        public DateFilter()
        {
            WithName(Consts.FilterConsts.DATE_FILTER)
                .AddParameter("date", NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.DateTime)
                .WithCondition("DATEPART(dayofyear,EntityTime) = DATEPART(dayofyear, :date)")
                ;
        }
    }
```

and in the mapping override:

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Stuff)
                .LazyLoad()
                .ReadOnly()
                .ApplyFilter<DateFilter>();
```

here's my configuration code.

```
Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                .DefaultSchema("dbo")               //set default schema to enable full-qualified queries
                .AdoNetBatchSize(batchSize > 0 ? batchSize : 1)
                .UseReflectionOptimizer()
                .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey(connectionStringKey))
                    .Cache(c => c.UseQueryCache()
                                    .ProviderClass(
                                    isWeb ? typeof(NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2.SysCacheProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName //in web environment- use sysCache2
                                        : typeof(NHibernate.Cache.HashtableCacheProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName //in dev environmet- use stupid cache
                                    )) 
                          )
                 .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(
                    AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Domain.Entity>(cfg)     //automapping the domain entities
                    .IncludeBase<Domain.SomethingBase>()               //ensure that although SomethingBase is a base class, map it as well. this enables us to store all Something sub-classes in the same table
                    .IncludeBase<Domain.OrOtherBase>()    //create a table for the abstract 'OrOtherBase' class
                    .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<MappingOverrides.MappingOverride>()
                    .Conventions.Add(DefaultCascade.All())      //make sure that all saves are cascaded (i.e when we save a zone, its queues are saved as well)
                    .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<IdGenerationWithHiLoConvention>()
                    ))
                 .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.Add(typeof(DateFilter)));
```

if I move the line before the automapping part, I get the exception:

```
 NHibernate.MappingException: filter-def for filter named 'DateFilter' was not found.
```

can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Me too - except it always gives me that latter error. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: nope. I actually gave up on it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so I figured this out. When you add the mappings separately like that, they end up in different mappings and it will either complain that you never use the filter or complain that it can't find the filter, because it's not looking both places. The solution is to add it directly to the automap, so in your case like:

```
//other stuff up here
.Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(() => {
    var a = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Domain.Entity>(cfg) 
                .IncludeBase<Domain.SomethingBase>() //and also cascades and conventions and stuff
    a.Add(typeof(DateFilter));
    return a;
 }));
```

Kinda gross because `.Add()` isn't fluent, but it does work.

Comment: I also submitted a patch to FluentNH to make this easier: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/pull/29