# NHibernate: QueryOver with leftjoin and Where

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, left-join

I'm using Fluent Nhibernate and I have to make a left join, so I need to use QueryOver (I prefer Query, but It doesn't have a good way to make a left join), but I can't have the result I expected.
I want a query like this one

```
select p.id_proyecto, p.titulo, c.id_compromiso from
sgc.proyecto p
left outer join sgc.compromiso c on p.id_proyecto = c.id_proyecto and c.id_solicitante  = 1
where
(p.id_creador = 1 or p.id_responsable = 1)
```

But I had this one

```
select p.id_proyecto, p.titulo, c.id_compromiso from
sgc.proyecto p
left outer join sgc.compromiso c on p.id_proyecto = c.id_proyecto 
where
(p.id_creador = 1 or p.id_responsable = 1) and c.id_solicitante = 1
```

Is there any way to do It in Fluent NHibernate?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in `NHibernate Filters` [here](http://ayende.com/blog/3993/nhibernate-filters)

You can deal Filters with Fluent configuration like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2435070/1486443)